# Are there any OSGi web service / SOAP clients out there?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, osgi

I'm looking for any webservice client that can be run inside an OSGi container and connect to a simple web service using SOAP,  doesn't sound so hard does it?

Oh, and it has to work under Java 1.5, so the JRE jax-ws wont be present.

The problem is I've tried a few solutions now, and although each solution works in standard Java using it from within OSGi doesn't.

- the springsource JAX-WS bundles seem to have dependency issues
- the CXF bundles get me as far as calling the service, but then can seem to find the stub methods in the proxy

Is there anyone out there who has successfully created an OSGi webservice client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to use Apache CXF Distributed OSGi (1) that is a reference implementation of OSGi Remote Services Specification.

Regards,
Dmytro

(1): http://cxf.apache.org/distributed-osgi.html